# zingchart convert english digits to non english digits

Tags: zingchart

In Angularjs I have written a filter and easily convert English digits to my language. but in Zingchart is there a way to convert English digits for show in scale-y and value-box?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using a non-standard font that for English digits unicode use destination language digits.